# Collection was modified exception. How it works under the hood?

Tags: c#

List will produce this exception if you modify collection during enumeration, but how it works? Does List set some flag internally every time you start enumeration and then checks for it at every method which modify collection? What if you enumerate same list multiple times? How it tracks its state?

Here basic example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var collection = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList();
        foreach(var item in collection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
            collection.RemoveAt(0); // how does list knows that we are enumerating collection?
        }
    }
}
```

I tired to google the answer, but there is nothing with a quick search. As far as I remember C# is not open source, so I can't check source code. Reflection is an option, but I rather save it as last resort.

Comment: "As far as I remember C# is not open source" a simple web search would answer that for you, preventing the need to remember it.

Comment: Here is a link answering your question: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646 (you are looking for `_version` field)

Comment: Not sure why you would need to know. Information Hiding Principle tells us that not having to know about design decisions is a good thing. All you need to know is that using enumerators after the List<T> was changed causes an exception. Relying on anything more specific is bad practice, as it may well change in the future.

Comment: @ThomasHilbert That's not a behavior of enumerations in general, it's the behavior of *the `List`'s enumerator* (and also other certain *specific* implementations of enumerables).

Comment: @ThomasHilbert There is a difference between knowing and relying. The better you understand how something works, the better you can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `List<T>` class contains a private field called `_version`. It's an integer that is incremented each time you add, remove, sort, or reverse the list.

When you start enumerating a list, `List` produces an enumerator instance that immediately takes a copy of the `_version` field and stores it in its own member variable called `version`. Each time you request an item from the enumerator, it checks to ensure `version == _version`. If the underlying list has changed, its version will have changed; when this is detected, the enumerator throws the exception you are seeing.

See [the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,d4efa2ca0a42221a) to view the implementation.